# Picklist required UNLESS other picklist is a specific value

Tags: picklist

I know how to make a field required using Validation Rules, and right now I have the following:

ISNULL(TR1__Language__c)

However -- if I want to make that field NOT required if a different picklist is a specific value, I'm not sure how to do that.

Please advise.

Comment: When you need to check multiple conditions, you need to use an `AND()`  function, see the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5).  This [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/validation_rules) has a good example.

Comment: N.B. use ISBLANK, not ISNULL, latter is deprecated